# When executing a query using java, how can I verify the results text when multiple rows are returned?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using JDBC to make a connection to SQL and execute a query. The query I am running will return 4 results, and I can print them using the below code.

```
Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
ResultSet result = (ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TransText FROM Glossary WHERE GlossID IN (SELECT GlossID FROM DBO.Resource WHERE TypeID=6)");
while(result.next()){
        String X = result.getString("TransText");
        System.out.println(X);
        }
```

Here are the results that are printed

```
TXT File
Multiple Languages
Resource A
Resource B
```

How can I verify the text of all 4 results that are returned from the query? I've  tried to use assertEquals, but its only verifies the text of the 1st row returned in the loop (TXT File)

```
Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
ResultSet result = (ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TransText FROM Glossary WHERE GlossID IN (SELECT GlossID FROM DBO.Resource WHERE TypeID=6)");
while(result.next()){
        String X = result.getString("TransText");
        System.out.println(X);
        Assert.assertEquals(X, "TXT File\nMultiple Languages\nResource A\nResource B");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> actualList = new ArrayList<>();
while(result.next()){
    actualList.add(result.getString("TransText"));
}
List<String> expectedList = Arrays.asList("TXT File", 
                                          "Multiple Languages", 
                                          "Resource A", 
                                          "Resource B");
assertEquals(expectedList, actualList);
```

If the order doesn't matter, use a Set rather than a List.

Answer (score 2):

Add each `String` into a `Set<String>`. Then, create an alternative `Set<String> expected` and fill it with the expected values. Then, compare if both `Set<String>`s are equals. I recommend a `Set` over a `List` since the results from your query may come in different order.

Here's how the test should look:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    List<String> results = retrieveFromDB();
    //name doesn't refer to ResultSet interface, it's just a coincidence
    Set<String> resultSet = new HashSet<String>(results);
    Set<String> expectedResults = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("expected1", "expected2", ...));
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResults, resultSet);
}
```

This approach assumes that there aren't repeated values from the query or that the number of repeated values from the query won't matter.

Comment: `Set` does not permit duplicates however, which might not be the correct logic to test. There are better ways to perform order-independent assertions on collections, either manually or with assertj.

Comment: @MattBall I don't know about those methods. Still, another approach is to use a `List`, sort it, then compare the results. I'll do some research about assertj on this.

Comment: `assertThat(someList).containsOnlyElementsOf(expectedList)`

Answer (score 2):

I would read all the results into a list and then use a library such as AssertJ to write the assertions (the library can be found at http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/).

As an example:

```
List<String> queryResults = new ArrayList<>();
Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
ResultSet result = (ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TransText FROM Glossary WHERE GlossID IN (SELECT GlossID FROM DBO.Resource WHERE TypeID=6)");
while(result.next()){
        String X = result.getString("TransText");
        queryResults.add(X);
        }

// AssertJ assertion
assertThat(queryResults).hasSize(4).contains('TXT file', 'Multiple Languages', 'Resource A', 'Resource B');
```

Comment: The DB does not guarantee any order of the returned result set.

Comment: The order does not matter for contains, and in this case as the four values are unique it satisfies the requirements. If the OP wanted to check the order and the value then a different assertion would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Create list from results and then compare that list

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while(result.next()){
   list.add(result.getString("TransText"));
}
```

Then iterate over list and compare is it matching to your result.

Create your expected result list.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

// add your expeted content in order

Then compare list using either asset or equals method.

```
if(list.equals(list1)){
 // write your logic here
}
```

OR

```
Assert.assertEquals(list1, list);
```